# Accessing Lists on a 2013 server instance from SharePoint Online App (Add-in)

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, office-365

Wondering if anyone may have any pointers or resources on how to authenticate and grab data from an on-premise instance of SharePoint, from an app hosted in SharePoint online.

I'm developing a new app in a SharePoint online (office365) tenant which will be pulling data from lists both within the Online tenant but also from another site on SharePoint Server 2013 hosted in Azure. At this point all I need is read-only from the server instance.

Currently I'm just working on the add-in as a sharepoint-hosted app and haven't been able to find any resources on how to do this client-side, if it's even possible?

Any help appreciated, Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone's wondering, solved by implementing CORS on the server instance, allowing the app web to access data. Not the greatest solution as only one domain can be whitelisted per server instance, but it works.